# How to send an SMS from the default messaging app on Android?

Tags: java, android, sms, android-contentprovider

I need the ability to both send and delete SMSes from my app. The code I'm using is shown. Sending an SMS does not require my app to be the default SMS app, however deleting does.

What is weird is that the code to send the SMS does work when the app is not default, but not when it is (the code to delete SMSes works the other way around, however this is expected).

I assume that this problem arises because even though another application may be sending the SMSes, only the default SMS app can write to the SMS provider, so I need to write to them manually. However, when having my app as default, other apps can still send SMSes using the same code provided, which is strange.

I have also tried writing to the SMS providers manually, specifically to content://sms/outbox and tocontent://sms/sent, none of which have worked. Although, the latter does display the message in the preinstalled SMS app.

```
    public static void sendSMS(String phoneNo, String msg, Context context) {
        try {
            SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
            smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, msg, null, null);
            Toast.makeText(context, "Message Sent",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(context,e.getMessage().toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

```
public static void deleteSMS(Context context, String message, String number) {
        try {
            Log.i(MainActivity.TAG, "delteSMS: try statement");
            Uri uriSms = Uri.parse("content://sms/sent");
            Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(uriSms,
                    new String[] { "_id", "thread_id", "address",
                            "person", "date", "body" }, null, null, null);

            if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    long id = c.getLong(0);
                    long threadId = c.getLong(1);
                    String address = c.getString(2);
                    String body = c.getString(5);
//                    Log.i(MainActivity.TAG, "Found SMS: " + body);

                    if (message.equals(body) && address.equals(number)) {
                        Log.i(MainActivity.TAG, "Deleting sms with" + threadId);
                        context.getContentResolver().delete(
                                Uri.parse("content://sms/" + id), null, null);
                    }
                } while (c.moveToNext());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i(MainActivity.TAG, "Could not delete SMS from inbox: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

TL;DR
I need to know how to send SMSes from an application which is set as default, since the usual procedure does not work.

Thanks

Comment: It's not quite clear how you're determining that it's not working. Sending still works the same when you're the default; the only difference is the one you've noted, that the default is responsible for writing its own outgoing messages to the Provider. Non-default apps using `SmsManager` will have their outgoing messages automatically saved to the Provider by the system. If you're assuming that your sends as the default aren't working just because they aren't showing up in the Provider, that's actually to be expected.

Comment: On the other hand, if you mean that the message is actually never reaching its recipient _only_ when you're the default, then that is a problem, but we'll need more details, and you'll need to do some tedious debugging. Lastly, I would also mention that some recent Android emulators have had buggy behavior when it comes to SMS, so it'd be a good idea to test on real devices, too, if possible.